# Oracle Sql ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE cititori( 
   index NUMBER(6),
   nume VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
   legitNr number(6) NOT NULL,
   legitElib DATE default SYSDATE, 
   legitValab DATE, 
   nastDate DATE,
   nastLoc VARCHAR2(20), 
   actSerie VARCHAR2(2),
   actNr NUMBER(8), 
   actAutorit VARCHAR2(20),
   actdatElib DATE, );
```

i cant find a solution for this error
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: remove comma before last );   ?

Comment: There are 500+ questions here on S.O. by searching for 'ORA-00904'. please do your due-dillegence. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Double quote `index`,is a reserved word,besides the extra comma or better yet change it to something else.

Comment: Better to change it to something else. If you double-quote it as is, you will end up with one lowercase column name (index) that always needs to be surrounded by quotes when queried, and the rest will be uppercase.